# RoundingMode.HALF_UP difference in scala and Java

Tags: java, scala, rounding, bigdecimal

In scala, I am trying to round up the following number to the 3 decimal precision using HALF_UP rounding mode. 
8409.3555

Unfortunately scala is returning 8409.356, but Java is returning 8409.355

Scala code:

```
def round(d: Double): Double = {
    BigDecimal.apply(d).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
}
```

Java code:

```
private static Double round(Double d) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    bd = bd.setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Is there any known issue?

Comment: How are you generating the `8409.3555` to pass to `round`? Both times in Scala? Have you tried calling the Java `round` from Scala, and vice versa?

Comment: I am generating as double "Double d = 8409.3555;"

Comment: I went with writing a java utility class and using that in scala code to keep the consistency.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't want to convert literal doubles to `BigDecimal` directly, because you may be bitten by floating point rounding errors. There is also a warning in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/?_ga=1.8468725.1939486482.1433104516#scala.math.BigDecimal):

> When creating a BigDecimal from a Double or Float, care must be taken as the binary fraction representation of Double and Float does not easily convert into a decimal representation

We can see it happen with `java.math.BigDecimal`:

```
scala> new java.math.BigDecimal(8409.3555)
res1: java.math.BigDecimal = 8409.355499999999665305949747562408447265625
```

When you try to round that number (half) up, it is now 8409.355. `scala.math.BigDecimal.apply` uses a `MathContext` to round the `Double` passed to `apply` immediately, so that the resulting `BigDecimal` has an increased chance of having the same value as the literal `Double` you passed in. Within the first snippet, what's *really* being called is:

```
scala> scala.math.BigDecimal(8409.3555)(java.math.MathContext.DECIMAL128)
res10: scala.math.BigDecimal = 8409.3555
```

It would be better to represent these literals as strings to avoid any rounding errors from storing the `Double`. For example:

```
scala> scala.math.BigDecimal("8409.3555")
res17: scala.math.BigDecimal = 8409.3555

scala> new java.math.BigDecimal("8409.3555")
res18: java.math.BigDecimal = 8409.3555
```

If you *must* convert from `Double`, I'd suggest using `scala.math.BigDecimal.apply` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I could also reproduce this issue.

```
def roundWithScala(d: Double): Double = {
    BigDecimal(d).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue()
}

def roundWithJava(d: Double): Double = {
    val bd = new java.math.BigDecimal(d).setScale(3, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
    return bd.doubleValue()
}

println(roundWithScala(8407.3555)) //8407.356
println(roundWithJava(8407.3555)) //8407.355

println(roundWithScala(8409.3555)) //8409.356
println(roundWithJava(8409.3555)) //8409.355

println(roundWithScala(8409.4555)) //8409.456
println(roundWithJava(8409.4555)) //8409.456
```

First thing I noticed is that Scala is using diffrent `MathContext` than Java.

I tried using same `MathContext.UNLIMITED` in both, but it didn't changed anything.

Then I noticed that in scala's `BigDecimal` java`s BigDecimal is constructed like this:

```
new BigDecimal(new BigDec(java.lang.Double.toString(d), mc), mc)
```

I tried using it in Java:

```
 val bd = new java.math.BigDecimal(java.lang.Double.toString(d), java.math.MathContext.UNLIMITED).setScale(3, java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

and I received same result (`8409.356`).

So basically the reason why you get diffrent result's is that double is transformed to string in scala's constructor.

Maybe you could use java's BigDecimal in your case (as I did in `roundWithJava`)?

Comment: I am actually rewriting a JAVA based ETL code to scala/spark based ETL. When I was comparing the old process result with the new process, I noticed this rounding error.  I was keen to use scala library, but now I am using Java library to make sure the results are consistent. Thanks